# Highlighting active Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I saw a code on a site, where it highlights the active cell .

The code is,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    Target.EntireColumn.Interior.ColorIndex = 20
    Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 20
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
End Sub
```

However, it's not working and I can't find an issue with it.
i am attaching the link from where I got the idea.

https://www.tiktok.com/@cheatsheets/video/7106111317416643882?is_from_webapp=1&sender_device=pc&web_id=7114635329407026689

Comment: Where did you put the code? What's the name of the Sub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is an event that runs automatically and therefore needs to be in the code section of the worksheet where you like to have this functionality. If you put it into a normal module it does not work! It has to be in a worksheet's code.

So if you want this in `Sheet1` the code needs to be inserted in the VBA Editor in `Sheet1`.

[image]

It then looks like this in `Sheet1`:

[image]